# ResourceBundle for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, message, resourcebundle

Is there any standard for storing localized messages on client side (JavaScript/HTML)?

Suppose a site supports several languages and I would like to pass a file with all possible error messages to client, what format would be the best format and how would I read it?

Also what are pros and cons of resolving error message text from some id on client- instead of server-side?

Answer (score 1):

XML or JSON, most likely. You can store the data for several locales quite easily using the JSON format:

```
{
    "locale": "fr-CA",
    "message": {
        "out-of-range": "Entrez un nombre entre 0 et 99."
    }
}
```

for example, and parse that into a simple object using `JSON.parse`, falling back on `eval`. Then you can access them quite easily:

```
var message = currentLocale.message['out-of-range'];
```

It's up to you how to load these.

Comment: Is this still the best way in 2018 or did some standard emerge in the meantime?

Comment: @KonradHöffner: There are a lot of gettext-style libraries that you can use, but the general idea is always the same, since it’s not a complicated one.